# How to render template only when it is populated?

Tags: html, image, angularjs, templates

I have a template for picture gallery which is populated with an ajax callback.
The problem is that before the template is populated, since it is looking for an image, I get a console error that the image is not found.

```
<img src="{{image.url}}" alt="{{image.alt}}">
```

How can I render this template only once there the data is available?

Comment: Use ng-src='image.url' instead.

Comment: it works, write it as an answer

Comment: @llyaD added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `src` which would be intially be null and hence the browser  makes a request for it. `ng-src` fixes it

`ng-src='image.url'`